# Alpha in the psych package

Tags: alpha, reliability, psych

I am working with the results of a test with 14 items, all of which are dichotomous (1 - right answer, 0 - wrong).
Is it possible to use omega to estimate reliability if I have dichotomous items?
Why does psych::alpha give a different coefficient of Alpha than psych::omega? In psych::alpha, it is Cronbach's alpha, and in psych::omega, it should be too, but there are different coefficients (0.64 and 0.75).

```
psych::omega(var1, poly=TRUE)
Alpha:                 0.75 
G.6:                   0.77 
Omega Hierarchical:    0.49 
Omega H asymptotic:    0.63 
Omega Total            0.78 


psych::alpha(x = var1)
raw_alpha std.alpha G6(smc) 
  0.64      0.64    0.63
```

Comment: Notice that for the call to omega, you specified poly=TRUE which means it will use the polychoric correlation (which, for dichotomous data is the same as tetrachoric correlation.  However, in the call to alpha, you did not specify using tetrachorics.  However, I do not recommend using tetracorics to find reliability estimates, for they will give inflated estimates.     You might also try the reliability function which gives even more estimates.